# It is hard to see what tag you are looking at

Tags: feature-request, tags, design

This is a screenshot of the [12.04](/questions/tagged/12.04) on Ask Ubuntu.

[image]

Looking over the page, you can see the Tag Wiki - but that doesn't show you what the tag is. In fact, the biggest text is the question count.

It's the same on other sites:

[image]

[image]

I think that the name of the tag should be more obvious on the page - larger text or in a different location.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is this off topic? I want it to be clearer what tag I'm looking at... "Support, feature requests, or bug reports for the core Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites" is welcome here. That applies here.

Comment: This concerns a specific site design; questions limited to a specific SE site should be posted on the child Meta for that site.

Comment: @Martin this is the same on all sites. Edited to have other sites on it.

Comment: This is still simply a design issue; and I can see the `12.04` tag just fine in your first screenshot; that's also a particularly 'narrow', easily missed tag text. You can already see the 'feature-request' tag in the Meta screenshot much more clearly.

Comment: @Martijn Yes, you can but it is still a valid feature request...

Answer (score -2):

> It is hard to see what tag you are looking at

I don't agree, and think it's just as easy to see as anything else, especially once one is familiar with the site layout.

1. As this is about the favourite tag, which has to be *manually
   selected*, surely users kinda know what tag they're viewing?
2. All the questions you are viewing have the tag repeated throughout
   them
3. The browser tab and title have the tag name in them

**Limited page space**

There's a large amount of information being served on each page, and they do really well providing a decent layout. I think there's logic and plenty of thought with placement, and what is and what isn't prominent.
And if you fill up the blank spaces (as per your proposal of moving the tag) then you end up with clutter, which worsens the problem you are discussing as then you can't see/find *anything*.

Besides, it's nice (in fact necessary) to have *some* blank space here and there, so your eyes can be drawn to the different areas with a break in between.

Also, if you move the tag to top of the page as per your image, you'd have to either move the question count as well, which brings clutter at the top, or split them up which is not logical.

I think it is fine where it is, as it is really.

> In fact, the biggest text is the question count

That's perfectly logical.
As the user has manually selected the tag, they know what it is, however they don't know what the question count is. So that is logically more prominent to provide *new/unknown information*.

### Update the tag wiki

This might resolve your issue:

If you view other tags, it's more clear which tag you are viewing by the wiki text, so I think perhaps the [12.04](/questions/tagged/12.04) wiki needs updating to add the tag reference somewhere.
EG

> Fourth LTS (Long Term Support) release of Ubuntu 12.04, code-named Precise Pangolin...[snip]..

In fact other version tags seem to suffer the same lack of detail.

Other tags are fine and negates the requirement of your proposal, really - such as [unity](/questions/tagged/unity):

> For questions regarding the **Unity** desktop environment